# Getting errors when manually setting breaks for dates in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to manually set the date interval of my x-axis to every 15 days (currently, it's daily) but I'm getting this error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only

I already converted my Date column using as.Date. For reference, this is the format of the Date column - YYYY-MM-DD

Here's the code I used:

base + scale_x_date(date_breaks = "15 days",date_labels = '%Y-%m-%d')

Comment: It will be much easier to help if you can make your code reproducible by sharing some example data and code that recreates the issue. Please include in your question the output of running `dput(head(YOUR_DATA))` and your ggplot2 code, in particular the part where you specify the x-axis mapping.

Comment: This simple example worked for me, so I expect there is something awry with your dates. `ggplot(data = data.frame(dates = as.Date(c("2022-07-20", "2022-05-20"))), aes(x = dates, y = 1)) + scale_x_date(date_breaks = "15 days",date_labels = '%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: yeah, i suspect something is wrong with the Dates - running dput(head(dat$Date)) gives me:
structure(c(18779, 18779, 18779, 18779, 18779, 18779), class = "Date") - my Date column looks like this 2021-06-01

Comment: @confusedpandah That `dput` output looks OK. Internally, date objects are stored as integers in R. The numbers match your expected dates like "2021-06-01". Can you please edit your question and include sample data as well as code.